# list all files in directory and subdirectories in linux with specific pattern filename

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, sh

i have some lot of files inside of directories and subdirectories like this :

```
108400344_2223_bab4.pdf
```

and

```
15.04.1150_bab4.pdf
```

I want to list and count all files which have a pattern like second one.
I'm using this command

```
ls -LR | grep bab4.pdf
```

but the command show all files including files which have a pattern with a name like the first one.
Any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that there is only one underscore:

```
ls -LR | grep '^[^_]*_bab4.pdf'
```